# Jquery ajax pass multiple values

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to pass multiple values with $.post ?

I'm tryed like this

```
$.post("page.php", {field: field,fieldtwo: fieldtwo}, function() {

        });
```

But it isn't working.I'm trying to pass two text fields, field and fieldtwo .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proper way.. assuming `field` and `fieldtwo` are input elements you should pass their value though:

```
$.post("page.php", {field: $("#field").val(), fieldtwo: $("#fieldtwo").val()}, function() {

});
```

Comment: Found the mistake, it was wrong character, and becouse of that the program was not starting i thinked that something was wrong, but .Still thanks :)